# Exporting data from a userform output into an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to ask whether anyone is familiar of a way to export data from a Userform listbox into a separate Worksheet.

For example, I have stored and displayed 3 columns ("Name", "Company" and "Position") together with multiple rows in a userform listbox and I want to transfer this into an Excel worksheet(with a click of a button) with the corresponding columns and rows.

Thanks for anyone who might provide any advice!

'Display the matching results with all parameters on new row of the results list

```
            Rownum = ResultsList.ListCount
            ResultsList.AddItem

            ResultsList.List(Rownum, 0) = Name.Value
            ResultsList.List(Rownum, 1) = Company.Value
            ResultsList.List(Rownum, 2) = Position.Value


    Else
    End If
 End Sub

 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets.Add = ResultsList.Value

 End Sub
```

I am essentially trying to get the result in "ResultsList" which is working ok, into a new sheet in excel.

Sorry for not adding in earlier.

Comment: Can you show me what you have tried so far, perhaps provide some example code?

Comment: Please see my edited version. Cheers!

Comment: Your question refers to a textbox, but `ResultsList` doesn't appear to be a textbox (a listbox perhaps?).

Comment: Oh, yes it's true! Sorry, I am new to VBA and I still confuse a lot of things... I am referring to listbox (if it makes a difference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to be what you are trying to do:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim m As Long, n As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    m = ResultsList.ListCount
    n = ResultsList.ColumnCount
    Set ws = Sheets.Add
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(m, n)).Value = ResultsList.List
End Sub
```

The code assumes that it is a multicolumn list and might fail with a single column (I haven't tested with that). It creates a new sheet, putting the values in the new sheet starting at A1. I'm not convinced that this is actually a good idea. I tend to find VBA code which creates new worksheets without good reason somewhat annoying -- so make sure that you have a good reason to put it on a new sheet rather than somewhere on a current sheet (perhaps at a user-selected location).

Comment: The code works perfectly for the purpose of creating a new sheet and displaying the information from the list. I guess you are right for the new sheet approach as it does add a new sheet each time instead of writing on the same one (when the button is clicked). Thank you, however, this code gave me some ideas for modifying my problem! Sorry for not being able to give your answer credits, as I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Glad to be of help. You could always accept the answer, if you want.

Comment: Am I able to store the information from the results list and put it into array, for the simple reason to put more information in the array which I don't want to display on the listbox but want to be exported to worksheet?

Comment: Variants can hold arrays -- including the list in a 2-dimensional list box. Just assign it to an array variable rather than the range. If you want to use it in your code after the userform closes, assign it to a public variable defined in a standard code module.

Comment: Yes, I did this but what confuses me is how to post the array in the new worksheet. So far the ways I have tried produce some kind of error which supposes that I just can't figure out the syntax.